# What is it called in AI when a program is designed to make "x in the style of y"?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, terminology

Simplified: *What is it called in AI when a program is designed to make "x in the style of y;" when it trains off of two types of sources in order to make a thing from source one, informed by features from source two?* For example, if a network made up of two smaller networks were to take sheet music of a specific compositional style in network A and audio samples from a certain genre in B and through an interface creates music from a certain genre in a certain compositional style; the *is* comes from One, the *seems* comes from Two.

For more coarse and obvious examples:

- "Compose synthpop in the style of Beethoven"
- "Draw impressionism in the style of Mondrian"
- "Generate casserole recipes using only ingredients most likely to fluctuate in price given current market data"
- "Sketch baseballs that look like they're made of espresso foam"

Comment: [Style Transfer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as "style transfer". 
The field was started by [Gatsys et al. in 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576.pdf), and has seen a lot of work over the last few years, including conditional translation from [Isola et al. in 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004) and unpaired translation from [Zhu et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10593.pdf).

This picture (Figure 2 from Gatsys et al.) shows the idea behind style transfer, and illustrates the dramatic results that are possible with these models.

[image]